# Performing Poorly org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(Authentication)

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I am trying to figure out why this is performing so poorly:

```
execution(Authentication org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(Authentication)) -> 
ELAPSED_TIME="592 ms"
```

I am using a org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider;

What can I log/capture to see why this is taking so long?

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Does it happen also on subsequent request?

Comment: Yes, the first time it takes about 1 second, all subsequent request are about 500MS

Comment: I suspect its latency connecting to the ldap server, but I am trying to figure out how to confirm that... I cant put networktraces on my box... Looking for a programmatic way of verifying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using LDAP authentication on first authenticate request that authentication must be verified against LDAP server (thats why it take so long for first request). I dont know exactly how LDAP Works but it seems that subsequent requests also have to be verified against server but already with some type of cache on LDAP server Side (thus faster response times).

Please see this thread:
[Slow authentication to LDAP Server on initial login attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24433182/slow-authentication-to-ldap-server-on-initial-login-attempt)

Comment: yeah, I knew that about the first request, but Im not rally concerned about the first request... I am concerned about the 500MS on subsequent requests... thats way too long.